# Cutting a Polygon with another polygon

Tags: java, polygon

I wanted to know how to get a new polygon from 2 existing polygons. 1 polygon is a regular polygon and the other Polygon has always 1 point at (0|0).The 2nd point is at the x-axis and the the 3rd point is at y-axis. The last point is always inside the other polygon.

[image]

I want to cut the piece out and get the new Coordinates of it and i want to have the new Coordinates of the old one without the piece.

[image]

My idea was to return the intersection points and try to figure out on which line it is to cut it out, but I am kinda stuck at it.

Comment: What are you looking for? An algorithm? Help with code you wrote?

Comment: Nice question :-) I would say : take all points from Pol1 who are located within Pol2, take all points from Pol2 who are located within Pol1, take the intersection points, and create your new polygon from all of those. But what when you have concave polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use JTS for this.
https://github.com/locationtech/jts
JTS is the de-facto standard library for such kind of operations.

I'd not use JavaFX for this (unless you are using it already as your GUI technology anyway) because since a few hours (the general availability of Java 11) it is not included in the Oracle JDK anymore.

Comment: Is it better than JavaFx or why should i take it?
I think that union and subtract is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Try using JavaFx [Polygon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.html). Polygon extends [shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html)  which has some functions you may find useful like [subtract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#subtract-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-) and [union](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#union-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-).
JavaFx is integrated with the Java SE 7 or higher.